# c# query on datetime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table which contains a column of `datetime` type. I want to query this table using Entity FrameWork given a specific `datetime` which inserted by user using `datetimePicker`.

The problem is in c# there is no `Date` type, only `DateTime` exists when ever is inserted it gets the `datetime` of that time, for example `24/8/2012 13:02;12`, but when get the value from `DatetimePicker` it gives me `24/8/2012 12:00:00` the two date aren't equal because of their times, and Entity Framework, so how to query on date using only date without time , or any alternative idea will be helpful

That is my code

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012,8,24);
var data = db.Tabel1.where(x=>x.Date.equals(dt));
```

Comment: have your seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
var Tomorrow = dt.Date.AddDays(1);
var data = db.Tabel1.where(x=>x.Date >= dt.Date && x.Date < Tomorrow);
```

Comment: Except that it's his Date in the database that contains the extra time information.

Comment: but this doesnt work . x.Date .s datetime

Comment: @rabarkareem: What is x.Date? A column in the table named "Date"?

Comment: Try my new code. I have updated it assuming that Date is a table column of DateTime type.

Comment: Yes it is a table column , bus this also doesnt work , it says : you cant use Functions in LINQ , dont let `.Date`

Comment: Yes , thats a smart idea , using > or <= makes it work , but this meas that using `.equals` we cant do this for exact date ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. But who cares when you have smart alternates like this :). However, you should note that `This behavior is by design.`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` as in:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012,8,24);
var data = db.Tabel1.where(x=> EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Date) == dt);
```

Comment: It gives me an exception on using EntityFunctions

Comment: @rabarkareem what is the exception?